# Python packaging in 2020

Tags: python, pip, packaging

I am trying to build good habits when developing my python applications and organize them as if they will always be used by others in the future. One crucial part of that is the packaging aspect.

I have read a certain amount of posts, discussions and the pep 517/518. However, I still don't fully understand how to properly organize my files for packaging.

I have decided to follow the `setup.cfg` path instead of the `pyproject.toml` path. That thing is clear. I shall identify the runtime necessary package in the `setup.cfg`.

I am also using `virtualenv` and I understood that development related package (`black`, `pytest,...`) should be defined in a separate file from `setup.cfg`, usually one called `requirements.txt`. One thing that is not clear: should `setup.cfg` be a subset of `requirements.txt` and therefore repeat some information? This seems bad practice and will at some point definitely become disconnected and hard to maintain.

I have tried to find an answer to that question. I found this [article](https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/) but I don't understand how adding this

```
--index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ 
-e .
```

in the requirements.txt helps avoid the issue or even handle the development dependencies.

I am even more lost when he presents the following possibility:

```
--index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ 
-e https://github.com/foo/bar.git#egg=bar
-e .
```

What does this achieve?

Finally, is the `setup.cfg` way compatible with the building of wheels package?

Comment: Great question - there is plenty of (often conflicting) folklore out there - it would be good to get a definitive view on this. Ideally one that ticks a specific number of boxes such as; Ease of deployment, reproducibility, simplicity and straightforwardness, understandable by end-users, and with some minimal element of surprise.

Comment: Curious why you are rejecting the `pyproject.toml` path. It seems like pypoetry makes things pretty easy for package management using them.

Comment: It seems, based on my readings, that setup.cfg is more widely supported. And as of today, there is no clear winner between them. So I thought... better to go the most supported route

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding: `requirements.txt` isn't used for dev dependencies. It's used for pinning a deployment, similar to what other languages call a lockfile. Yes `setup.cfg` will list a subset of the dependencies already mentioned in `requirements.txt` (because the former only lists your direct dependencies, not transitive). But it's not exactly duplication of info, because in setup you have the compatibility specifiers such as upper or lower bounds, whereas requirements.txt should be all `==` pins. I agree with Andrew that pyproject.toml is a much better choice than setup.cfg.

Comment: Btw it usually doesn't matter much what is most "supported" by the user of the package, because once you've publish a wheel file, the setup.py/setup.cfg are not even in there. They don't go into the wheel. It's only your development machine which builds the distribution where you need to have the recent enough versions of setuptools etc.  Unless you want to publish sdist (which is another can of worms entirely), then the build environment remains within your own control.

Comment: @wim it is incorrect to state that you can only pin dependencies in a requirement file, actually you can add upper, lower bounds or even wildcard version numbers as well. As a rule of thumb I usually use requirement.txt for applications like web services that are not packaged for distribution and setup.py for packages. But you can also combine the two, like when I dockerize a package I usually use requirements.txt to cache the pip install in my container and save a lot of build time.

Answer (score 1):

I usually follow the two approaches below to separate the list of dev dependencies from runtime dependencies in my packages:

### Approach #1

In my `setup.py` configuration file I use the `extras_require` field to define development related dependencies like this:

`setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

INSTALL_REQUIRES = ["python-dotenv"]
EXTRAS_REQUIRE = {
    "dev": ["flake8", "black", "mypy"],
}


setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="0.1.0",
    description="My awesome package",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=INSTALL_REQUIRES,
    extras_require=EXTRAS_REQUIRE,
    python_requires=">=3.8",
)
```

As you can see above I have an `EXTRAS_REQUIRE` dictionary with a `dev` key where I list my dev dependencies.
Then I can use `pip` to install the package. If I want to exclude the installation I just do `pip install .`, this way only the required `python-dotenv` and obviously the `mypackage` packages will be installed in your given environment.
However if you want to include the development related dependencies you can specify the extra install like this `pip install .['dev']`, then all your dev deps will get installed in the environment as well.

### Approach #2

In case you insist to have your dev requirements in a separate requirements file, you can also do that, let's call it `requirements-dev.txt` and populate it like this:

`requirements-dev.txt`

```
.  # note the dot here, this will tell pip to include the install_requires deps from your setup.py
flake8
black
mypy
```

and modify the previous `setup.py` by deleting the extras dictionary:

`setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

INSTALL_REQUIRES = ["python-dotenv"]

setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="0.1.0",
    description="My awesome package",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=INSTALL_REQUIRES,
    python_requires=">=3.8",
)
```

Then you can install your package like `pip install -r requirements-dev.txt` and if you don't want to install dev dependencies you just do the regular `pip install .` and that's it.